# How to get the Matter device abilities list by Google Home Service Mobile SDK?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home, matter-iot-standard

By [Google Home Sample App for Matter](https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/matter-sample-app#1), it seems nothing we can know about the device clusters from the device after commissioning.

```
// commission
Matter.getCommissioningClient(context)
        .commissionDevice(commissionDeviceRequest)
```

After commissioning, it did the addDeviceState.

```
    val newDeviceState =
        DeviceState.newBuilder()
            .setDeviceId(deviceId)
            .setDateCaptured(getTimestampForNow())
            .setOnline(isOnline)
            .setOn(isOn)
            .build()
```

But why it knows there is a `setOn()` for the device? How to know what clusters the device has?

I have read the [Google Play service Matter API](https://developers.home.google.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/home/matter/package-summary) but there are only commission and share APIs. Are there Matter devices setting function list?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://developers.home.google.com/samples/matter-app?hl=en

> Note: The sample app currently only supports devices that have the On/Off server attribute, for example lights, smart plugs, and fans.

Due to this, the app always assumes that any Matter device that is commissioned via GHSAFM supports the on/off cluster.

Comment: I found the sample code using `chip.devicecontroller.ChipClusters` in the 3rd party library to get and set the Matter clusters. So maybe Google Home Mobile SDK won't support Matter control ability directly.